# How to learn a reason why a 3rd party, non-debuggable app crashed

Tags: android

In Android, is there a way to tell why app crashed on my device? Let's say I have root access to the device, but the app that crashed is not debuggable and does not print anything to logcat.

Just to reiterate, **the app that crashed is not my app, I have no access to the source, and it's not debuggable (it's a release build)**. I just want to get any available insights on why it crashed.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I only found the `/data/anr/` and `/data/tombstones` as sources for potential information. Those do not contain the stacktraces. Is there anything more available?

EDIT: There is a lot of confusion in comments, please read the question carefully. What I'm after is some kind of low level component that knows about the reason of the crash. The virtual machine must know, right?

Comment: Check my updated description.

Comment: @kar use exception debug, you may find the error or cause

Comment: What is "exception debug"?

Comment: You can go for https://try.crashlytics.com/. You can get crash report remotely.

Comment: integrate crashlytics or crittercism to your app to get the logs

Comment: and enable exception debug

Comment: Guys... please read the question carefully. The scenario does not involve me having access to the app, nor it is debuggable.

Comment: @kar, please read above comments. We read question very carefully and gave reply for crashalytics and crittercism.

Comment: He means he can get crash report from user, not from development time :) I think it's easy for understanding his ideas.

Comment: Of course, @ChintanRathod has recommended you a service (that I also post in my post) named `Crashlytics`. You can get a try :)

Comment: But you have not defined the purpose why you want crash report for 3rd party application? What will you do after fetching them? Probably you can use logs and send each interval and examine them.

Comment: My app is causing another app to crash. I want to understand why. As I mentioned logs don't contain any useful information in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cannot.**  In third-party app, you cannot get detail about crash report. In some rarely case, third-party application has saved crash reports to log file. If you know file location, you can analyze crash on that log file. Otherwise, there isn't any way.

In case you develop your own app, and your application already has released to user and you want to get some statistic about crash event. You can gain some insight by using Crash Report Service as I mention below.

In case you want go get crash report from your own application, here is some libraries and services for your: [ACRA library](http://www.acra.ch/). Crash report will generated and post to Google Form. Really easy to use and setup in your application. As document stated:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.yourselectedbackend.com/reportpath")

    public class MyApplication extends Application {
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
      }
    }
```

But you must have your own server. (There are tutorials for deploying this server, but you still must have your own). If you want to depend all to **third-party service** then [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) or [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) or [Countly](https://count.ly/crash-reports/) or [Google search query](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20crash%20report%20service)

Comment: This obviously won't help me to gain any insights about a third party app, which is what I'm after.

Comment: @kar No. you cannot get information about why it's crash from third-party app. Maybe some app stores a log file somewhere (and they will tell you). Otherwise, cannot. I'm sorry

Comment: No. you understand wrong my idea. In case you develop your app, and your application already has released to user, you can't know why it's crash all all related statistic about crash event. Nevertheless you can gain some insight by using Crash Report Service as I mention above. In third-party app, again, **you cannot**.  That's all. And that's the answer you need.

Comment: Well it wasn't me, but your answer does not answer the question itself. Your comments do, so you may make them an answer, and I'll accept it if noone else will be able to provide more details.

Comment: I have updated answer. Hope this help you and other people have same problems with you :)

Answer (score 1):

I identified following sources that may or may not have useful information about 3rd party apps crashes:

- `adb logcat -b crash`
- `/data/tombstones/`
- `/data/anr/`